# Group theory tables

Tags: discussion

#### Warning: very MathJax heavy.

To avoid MathJax issues, please do not link to the individual answers on this post. Instead, link to the question where users will be shown this guidance.

> If you are using this on a computer: **Please let the MathJax load (~1 minute) BEFORE clicking any of the *desktop* links below.** This avoids the issues associated with MathJax-heavy answers (namely, the page jumps to the top of the desired answer before the MathJax loads; when the MathJax loads, the desired answer is no longer on your screen). To get back to the table of contents, **use the *(back to top)* links**. These also avoid refreshing the page.
>
> If you are using this on a mobile device: **Please use the *mobile* links provided below.** These are direct links to the answers and work just fine (tested on iOS 10, 22-11-2016). Hyperlinks to anchors don't work on mobile, hence the need for these.
>
> You can **sort by active** to view the answers in their intended order.

1. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3436) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3436/) Low-symmetry groups: $C_1$, $C_\mathrm{s}$, $C_\mathrm{i}$
2. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3441) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3441/) $C_n$ $(2 \leq n \leq 8)$
3. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3447) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3447/) $D_n$ $(2 \leq n \leq 6)$
4. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3448) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3448/) $C_{n\mathrm{v}}$ $(2 \leq n \leq 6)$
5. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3449) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3449/) $C_{n\mathrm{h}}$ $(2 \leq n \leq 6)$
6. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3450) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3450/) $D_{n\mathrm{h}}$ $(2 \leq n \leq 6)$
7. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3451) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3451/) $D_{n\mathrm{d}}$ $(2 \leq n \leq 6)$
8. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3452) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3452/) $S_n$ $(n = 4, 6, 8)$
9. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3443) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3443/) Cubic groups: $T, T_\mathrm{d}, T_\mathrm{h}, O, O_\mathrm{h}$
10. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3453) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3453/) Icosahedral groups: $I, I_\mathrm{h}$
11. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3438) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3438/) $C_{\infty\mathrm{v}}$ and $D_{\infty\mathrm{h}}$
12. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3437) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3437) The full rotation group $\mathrm{R}_3$
13. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3442) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3442/) Direct product tables
14. [**Desktop**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3454) | [**Mobile**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3454/) Tables of descent in symmetry

These tables are taken from [the OUP website](http://global.oup.com/uk/orc/chemistry/qchem2e/student/tables/). There are some typographical corrections which were distributed internally in my university, and I spotted some errors myself. I have corrected the tables where necessary.

The character tables have also been checked against Appendix IIA in F.A. Cotton's *Chemical Applications of Group Theory*, 3rd ed.

Schönflies symbols are used throughout.

Comment: There’s also [this reference](http://www.pci.tu-bs.de/aggericke/PC2/Punktgruppen/Punktgruppen.htm) from the TU Braunschweig in case anybody wants to double-check against removed or left typos/errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### Low-symmetry groups: $C_1$, $C_\mathrm{s}$, $C_\mathrm{i}$

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\hline
C_1 & E \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cc|cc}
\hline
C_\mathrm{s} (= C_\mathrm{h}) & E & \sigma_\mathrm{h} & &  \\ \hline
\mathrm{A'} & 1 & 1 & x,y, R_z & x^2, y^2, z^2, xy \\
\mathrm{A''} & 1 & -1 & z, R_x, R_y & xz, yz \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cc|cc}
\hline
C_\mathrm{i} (= S_2) & E & i & &  \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_g} & 1 & 1 & R_x, R_y, R_z & x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, xz, yz \\
\mathrm{A_u} & 1 & -1 & x,y,z &  \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Answer (score 3):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#) $\,\,\,$

### Direct product tables

- The tables are symmetric about the diagonal.
- For point groups without subscripted irreps (i.e. the irreps are simply $\mathrm{A}$, $\mathrm{B}$, $\mathrm{E}$, $\mathrm{T}$), simply treat $\mathrm{A_1} \equiv \mathrm{A_2} \equiv \mathrm{A}$, etc.
- Square brackets $[\;]$ are used to indicate the representation spanned by the antisymmetrised product of a degenerate representation with itself.*

#### General

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\hline
 & \mathrm{g} & \mathrm{u} \\ \hline
\mathrm{g} & \mathrm{g} & \mathrm{u} \\
\mathrm{u} &  & \mathrm{g} \\ \hline
\end{array}
 & \hspace{10pt}
 & 
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\hline
 & \mathrm{'} & \mathrm{''} \\ \hline
\mathrm{'} & \mathrm{'} & \mathrm{''} \\
\mathrm{''} &  & \mathrm{'} \\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

$\,$

#### $C_2, C_3, C_6, D_3, D_6, C_\mathrm{2v}, C_\mathrm{3v}, C_\mathrm{6v}, C_\mathrm{2h}, C_\mathrm{3h}, C_\mathrm{6h}, D_\mathrm{3h}, D_\mathrm{6h}, D_\mathrm{3d}, S_6$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\hline
 & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} \\
\mathrm{A_2} & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2}\\
\mathrm{B_1} & & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_1} \\
\mathrm{B_2} & & & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_1} \\
\mathrm{E_1} & & & & & \mathrm{A_1 + [A_2] + E_2} & \mathrm{B_1 + B_2 + E_1} \\
\mathrm{E_2} & & & & & & \mathrm{A_1 + [A_2] + E_2} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

#### $D_2, D_\mathrm{2h}$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\hline
 & \mathrm{A} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{B_3} \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & \mathrm{A} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{B_3} \\
\mathrm{B_1} & & \mathrm{A} & \mathrm{B_3} & \mathrm{B_2} \\
\mathrm{B_2} & & & \mathrm{A} & \mathrm{B_1} \\
\mathrm{B_3} & & & & \mathrm{A} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

#### $C_4, D_4, C_\mathrm{4v}, C_\mathrm{4h}, D_\mathrm{4h}, D_\mathrm{2d}, S_4$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\hline
 & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{E} \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{E} \\
\mathrm{A_2} & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{E} \\
\mathrm{B_1} & & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{E} \\
\mathrm{B_2} & & & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{E} \\
\mathrm{E} & & & & & \mathrm{A_1 + [A_2] + B_1 + B_2} \\ \hline 
\end{array}$$

$\,$

#### $C_5, D_5, C_\mathrm{5v}, C_\mathrm{5h}, D_\mathrm{5h}, D_\mathrm{5d}$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc} \hline
 & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} \\
\mathrm{A_2} & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} \\
\mathrm{E_1} & & & \mathrm{A_1 + [A_2] + E_2} & \mathrm{E_1 + E_2} \\
\mathrm{E_2} & & & & \mathrm{A_1 + [A_2] + E_1}  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

#### $D_\mathrm{4d}, S_8$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}\hline
 & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_3} \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_3} \\
\mathrm{A_2} & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_3} \\
\mathrm{B_1} & & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{E_3} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_1} \\
\mathrm{B_2} & & & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{E_3} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_1} \\
\mathrm{E_1} & & & & & \mathrm{A_1 + [A_2] + E_2} & \mathrm{E_1 + E_3} & \mathrm{B_1 + B_2 + E_2} \\
\mathrm{E_2} & & & & & & \mathrm{A_1 + [A_2] + B_1 + B_2} & \mathrm{E_1 + E_3} \\
\mathrm{E_3} & & & & & & & \mathrm{A_1 + [A_2] + E_2} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

### $T, T_\mathrm{h}, T_\mathrm{d}, O, O_\mathrm{h}$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc} \hline
 & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{E} & \mathrm{T_1} & \mathrm{T_2} \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{E} & \mathrm{T_1} & \mathrm{T_2} \\
\mathrm{A_2} & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{E} & \mathrm{T_2} & \mathrm{T_1} \\
\mathrm{E} & & & \mathrm{A_1 + [A_2] + E} & \mathrm{T_1 + T_2} & \mathrm{T_1 + T_2} \\
\mathrm{T_1} & & & & \mathrm{A_1 + E + [T_1] + T_2} & \mathrm{A_2 + E + T_1 + T_2} \\
\mathrm{T_2} & & & & & \mathrm{A_1 + E + [T_1] + T_2} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

#### $D_\mathrm{6d}$

$$\small\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc} \hline
 & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_3} & \mathrm{E_4} & \mathrm{E_5} \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_3} & \mathrm{E_4} & \mathrm{E_5} \\
\mathrm{A_2} & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{B_2} & \mathrm{B_1} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_3} & \mathrm{E_4} & \mathrm{E_5} \\
\mathrm{B_1} & & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{A_2} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_3} & \mathrm{E_4} & \mathrm{E_5} \\
\mathrm{B_2} & & & & \mathrm{A_1} & \mathrm{E_1} & \mathrm{E_2} & \mathrm{E_3} & \mathrm{E_4} & \mathrm{E_5} \\
\mathrm{E_1} & & & & & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{A_1 + [A_2]}\\ \mathrm{+ E_2}\quad\end{aligned} & \mathrm{E_1 + E_3} & \mathrm{E_2 + E_4} & \mathrm{E_3 + E_5} & \mathrm{B_1 + B_2 + E_4} \\
\mathrm{E_2} & & & & & & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{A_1 + [A_2]}\\ \mathrm{+ E_4}\quad\end{aligned} & \mathrm{E_1 + E_5} & \mathrm{B_1 + B_2 + E_2} & \mathrm{E_3 + E_5} \\
\mathrm{E_3} & & & & & & & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{A_1 + [A_2]}\\ \mathrm{+ B_1 + B_2}\end{aligned} & \mathrm{E_1 + E_5} & \mathrm{E_2 + E_4} \\
\mathrm{E_4} & & & & & & & & \mathrm{A_1 + [A_2] + E_4} & \mathrm{E_1 + E_3} \\
\mathrm{E_5} & & & & & & & & & \mathrm{A_1 + [A_2] + E_2} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

#### $I, I_\mathrm{h}$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc} \hline
 & \mathrm{A} & \mathrm{T_1} & \mathrm{T_2} & \mathrm{G} & \mathrm{H} \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & \mathrm{A} & \mathrm{T_1} & \mathrm{T_2} & \mathrm{G} & \mathrm{H} \\
\mathrm{T_1} & & \mathrm{A + [T_1] + H} & \mathrm{G + H} & \mathrm{T_2 + G + H} & \mathrm{T_1 + T_2 + G + H} \\
\mathrm{T_2} & & & \mathrm{A + [T_2] + H} & \mathrm{T_1 + G + H} & \mathrm{T_1 + T_2 + G + H} \\
\mathrm{G} & & & & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{A + [T_1 + T_2]}\\\mathrm{+ G + H}\quad\,\,\end{aligned} & \mathrm{T_1 + T_2 + G + 2H} \\
\mathrm{H} & & & & & \mathrm{A + [T_1 + T_2 + G] + G + 2H} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

#### $C_\mathrm{\infty v}, D_\mathrm{\infty h}$

In general: 
$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc} \hline
\Lambda = & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots \\ \hline
 & \Sigma & \Pi & \Delta & \Phi & \Gamma & \cdots \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{align}
\Lambda_1 \times \Lambda_2 &= |\Lambda_1 - \Lambda_2| + (\Lambda_1 + \Lambda_2) \\
\Lambda \times \Lambda &= \Sigma^+ + [\Sigma^-] + 2\Lambda
\end{align}$$

For the first few irreps:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc} \hline
 & \Sigma^+ & \Sigma^- & \Pi & \Delta & \cdots \\ \hline
\Sigma^+ & \Sigma^+ & \Sigma^- & \Pi & \Delta & \cdots \\ 
\Sigma^- & & \Sigma^+ & \Pi & \Delta & \cdots \\
\Pi & & & \Sigma^+ + [\Sigma^-] + \Delta & \Pi + \Phi & \cdots \\
\Delta & & & & \Sigma^+ + [\Sigma^-] + \Gamma & \cdots \\
\vdots & & & & & \ddots \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

#### The full rotation group, $\mathrm{R_3}$

$$\begin{align}
\Gamma^{(j)} \times \Gamma^{(j')} &= \Gamma^{(j+j')} + \Gamma^{(j+j'-1)} + \cdots + \Gamma^{(|j-j'|)} \\
\Gamma^{(j)} \times \Gamma^{(j)} &= \Gamma^{(2j)} + \Gamma^{(2j-2)} + \cdots + \Gamma^{(0)} + \left[\Gamma^{(2j-1)} + \Gamma^{(2j-3)} + \cdots + \Gamma^{(1)}\right]
\end{align}$$

<sub>*The direct product of a degenerate species with itself may be resolved into a symmetric direct product, and an anti-symmetric direct product. In vibrational spectroscopy, the symmetry species of the overtones of a degenerate fundamental are obtained from the symmetric direct products. In the determination of electronic terms, the symmetric and anti- symmetric direct products for orbital angular momentum are taken with the appropriate spin functions to ensure that the total wave functions are anti-symmetric.</sub>

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Answer (score 2):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### Cubic groups: $T, T_\mathrm{d}, T_\mathrm{h}, O, O_\mathrm{h}$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|cc}\hline
T & E & 4C_3 & 4C_3^2 & 3C_2 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/3) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2+z^2 \\
\mathrm{E} & \left\{ \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned}\right\} & & (2z^2-x^2-y^2,x^2-y^2) \\
\mathrm{T} & 3 & 0 & 0 & -1 & (x,y,z),(R_x,R_y,R_z) & (xy,xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\small\begin{array}{c|cccccccc|cc} \hline
T_\mathrm{h} & E & 4C_3 & 4C_3^2 & 3C_2 & i & 4S_6 & 4S_6^5 & 3\sigma_\mathrm{d} & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/3) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_g} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2+z^2 \\
\mathrm{E_g} & \left\{ \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned} 1\\ 1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right\} & & \begin{aligned}(2z^2-x^2-y^2,\\ x^2-y^2)\,\,\,\,\,\, \end{aligned} \\ 
\mathrm{T_g} & 3 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & -1 & (R_x,R_y,R_z) & (xy,xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{A_u} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_u} & \left\{ \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned} 1\\ 1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned}\right\} & & \\ 
\mathrm{T_u} & 3 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & (x,y,z) & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc|cc} \hline
T_\mathrm{d} & E & 8C_3 & 3C_2 & 6S_4 & 6\sigma_\mathrm{d} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1    & 1    & 1    & 1  & & x^2+y^2+z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1    & 1    & -1   & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{E}   & 2 & -1   & 2    & 0    & 1  & & (2z^2-x^2-y^2,x^2-y^2) \\
\mathrm{T_1} & 3 & 0    & -1   & 1    & -1 & (R_x,R_y,R_z) & \\
\mathrm{T_2} & 3 & 0    & -1   & -1   & 1  & (x,y,z) & (xy,xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc|cc}\hline
O & E & 8C_3 & 3C_2 = C_4^2 & 6C_4 & 6C_2' & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2+z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{E} & 2 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & & (2z^2-x^2-y^2,x^2-y^2) \\
\mathrm{T_1} & 3 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & (x,y,z),(R_x,R_y,R_z) & \\
\mathrm{T_2} & 3 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & & (xy,xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\small\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc|cc}\hline
O_\mathrm{h} & E & 8C_3 & 6C_2 & 6C_4 & \begin{aligned}3C_2 \\ \scriptsize=C_4^2\end{aligned} & i & 6S_4 & 8S_6 & 3\sigma_\mathrm{h} & 6\sigma_\mathrm{d} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_{1g}} & 1  & 1  & 1  & 1  & 1  & 1  & 1  & 1  & 1  & 1  & & x^2+y^2+z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_{2g}} & 1  & 1  & -1 & -1 & 1  & 1  & -1 & 1  & 1  & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_g}    & 2  & -1 & 0  & 0  & 2  & 2  & 0  & -1 & 2  & 0  & & \begin{aligned}(2z^2-x^2-y^2,\\ x^2-y^2)\,\,\,\,\,\, \end{aligned} \\
\mathrm{T_{1g}} & 3  & 0  & -1 & 1  & -1 & 3  & 1  & 0  & -1 & -1 & (R_x,R_y,R_z) & \\
\mathrm{T_{2g}} & 3  & 0  & 1  & -1 & -1 & 3  & -1 & 0  & -1 & 1  & & (xy,xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{A_{1u}} & 1  & 1  & 1  & 1  & 1  & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1  & & \\
\mathrm{A_{2u}} & 1  & 1  & -1 & -1 & 1  & -1 & 1  & -1 & -1 & 1  & & \\
\mathrm{E_u}    & 2  & -1 & 0  & 0  & 2  & -2 & 0  & 1  & -2 & 0  & & \\
\mathrm{T_{1u}} & 3  & 0  & -1 & 1  & -1 & -3 & -1 & 0  & 1  & 1  & (x,y,z) & \\
\mathrm{T_{2u}} & 3  & 0  & 1  & -1 & -1 & -3 & 1  & 0  & 1  & -1 & & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Answer (score 2):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### $C_{n\mathrm{v}} (2 \leq n \leq 6)$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{2v} & E & C_2 & \sigma_\mathrm{v}(xz) & \sigma_\mathrm{v}'(yz) & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & z & x^2, y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & R_z & xy \\
\mathrm{B_1} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & x, R_y & xz \\
\mathrm{B_2} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & y, R_x & yz \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{3v} & E & 2C_3 & 3\sigma_\mathrm{v} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\ 
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & -1 & R_z &  \\ 
\mathrm{E} & 2 & -1 & 0 & (x,y), (R_x,R_y) & (x^2-y^2,xy), (xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{4v} & E & 2C_4 & C_2 & 2\sigma_\mathrm{v} & 2\sigma_\mathrm{d} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{B_1} & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & & x^2-y^2 \\
\mathrm{B_2} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & & xy \\ 
\mathrm{E} & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & (x,y),(R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{5v} & E & 2C_5 & 2C_5^2 & 5\sigma_\mathrm{v} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{E_1} & 2 & 2\cos 72^\circ & 2\cos 144^\circ & 0 & (x,y),(R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_2} & 2 & 2\cos 144^\circ & 2\cos 72^\circ & 0 & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\\hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{6v} & E & 2C_6 & 2C_3 & C_2 & 3\sigma_\mathrm{v} & 3\sigma_\mathrm{d} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & z & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{B_1} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{B_2} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_1} & 2 & 1 & -1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & (x,y),(R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_2} & 2 & -1 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Answer (score 2):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### Tables of descent in symmetry

These tables show the correlations between the irreps of an overgroup with those of some of its subgroups.
$\newcommand{\mirror}[1]{\sigma_\mathrm{#1}}
\newcommand{\rowthree}[3]{\mathrm{#1}&\mathrm{#2}&\mathrm{#3}\\}
\newcommand{\rowfour}[4]{\mathrm{#1}&\mathrm{#2}&\mathrm{#3}&\mathrm{#4}\\}
\newcommand{\rowfive}[5]{\mathrm{#1}&\mathrm{#2}&\mathrm{#3}&\mathrm{#4}&\mathrm{#5}\\}
\newcommand{\rowsix}[6]{\mathrm{#1}&\mathrm{#2}&\mathrm{#3}&\mathrm{#4}&\mathrm{#5}&\mathrm{#6}\\}
\newcommand{\rowseven}[7]{\mathrm{#1}&\mathrm{#2}&\mathrm{#3}&\mathrm{#4}&\mathrm{#5}&\mathrm{#6}&\mathrm{#7}\\}
\newcommand{\roweight}[8]{\mathrm{#1}&\mathrm{#2}&\mathrm{#3}&\mathrm{#4}&\mathrm{#5}&\mathrm{#6}&\mathrm{#7}&\mathrm{#8}\\}$

- A sub-heading $A$ identifies which symmetry element(s) in the overgroup is/are preserved as symmetry element(s) in the subgroup.
- A sub-heading $A \to B$ indicates that symmetry element $A$ in the overgroup becomes symmetry element $B$ in the subgroup.
- In the subgroup $C_\mathrm{s}$ there is only one mirror plane, and therefore no ambiguity. However, in $C_\mathrm{2v}$ there are two mirror planes. Which mirror plane becomes $\mirror{v}$, and which becomes $\mirror{v}'$, cannot be uniquely defined and must be set by a convention. This convention is either indicated clearly, or omitted if it does not affect the resulting irreps (because they appear together as a sum $\mathrm{B_1 + B_2}$). In the latter case, this is indicated by a dagger symbol, $^\dagger$. Similar ambiguity is present in the three degenerate rotation axes of $D_2$ and $D_\mathrm{2h}$.

Tables for any omitted overgroups, as well as correlations for most omitted subgroups (listed below each table), can be found in Appendix X-8 of *Molecular Vibrations: The Theory of Infrared and Raman Vibrational Spectra* by Wilson, Decius, and Cross. The tables presented here have been checked against this source. If I have time, I may add more tables from there.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\begin{array}{c|ccc} \hline
C_\mathrm{2v} & C_2 & C_\mathrm{s} & C_\mathrm{s} \\
              &     & \sigma(xz)   & \sigma(yz) \\ \hline
\rowfour{A_1}{A}{A' }{A' }
\rowfour{A_2}{A}{A''}{A''}
\rowfour{B_1}{B}{A' }{A''}
\rowfour{B_2}{B}{A''}{A' } \hline
\end{array} & \quad &
\begin{array}{c|ccc} \hline
C_\mathrm{3v} & C_3 & C_\mathrm{s} \\ \hline
\rowthree{A_1}{A}{A'    }
\rowthree{A_2}{A}{A''   }
\rowthree{E  }{E}{A'+A''} \hline
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{4v} & C_\mathrm{2v} & C_\mathrm{2v} \\
              & \mirror{v}    & \mirror{d}    \\ \hline
\rowthree{A_1}{A_1    }{A_1    }
\rowthree{A_2}{A_2    }{A_2    }
\rowthree{B_1}{A_1    }{A_2    }
\rowthree{B_2}{A_2    }{A_1    }
\rowthree{E  }{B_1+B_2}{B_1+B_2}\hline
\end{array} \\
\text{also: }C_4, C_2, C_\mathrm{s}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc} \hline
D_\mathrm{2h} &  D_2  & C_\mathrm{2v} & C_\mathrm{2v} & C_\mathrm{2v} & C_\mathrm{2h} & C_\mathrm{2h} & C_\mathrm{2h} \\
              &       & C_2(z)        & C_2(y)        & C_2(x)        & C_2(z)        & C_2(y)        & C_2(x)        \\ \hline
\roweight{A_g   }{A  }{A_1}{A_1}{A_1}{A_g}{A_g}{A_g}
\roweight{B_{1g}}{B_1}{A_2}{B_2}{B_1}{A_g}{B_g}{B_g}
\roweight{B_{2g}}{B_2}{B_1}{A_2}{B_2}{B_g}{A_g}{B_g}
\roweight{B_{3g}}{B_3}{B_2}{B_1}{A_2}{B_g}{B_g}{A_g}
\roweight{A_u   }{A  }{A_2}{A_2}{A_2}{A_u}{A_u}{A_u}
\roweight{B_{1u}}{B_1}{A_1}{B_1}{B_2}{A_u}{B_u}{B_u}
\roweight{B_{2u}}{B_2}{B_2}{A_1}{B_1}{B_u}{A_u}{B_u}
\roweight{B_{3u}}{B_3}{B_1}{B_2}{A_1}{B_u}{B_u}{A_u} \hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc} \hline
D_\mathrm{2h} & C_2    & C_2    & C_2    & C_\mathrm{s} & C_\mathrm{s} & C_\mathrm{s} \\
\text{cont.}  & C_2(z) & C_2(y) & C_2(x) & \mirror{xy}  & \mirror{zx}  & \mirror{yz}  \\ \hline
\rowseven{A_g   }{A}{A}{A}{A' }{A' }{A' }
\rowseven{B_{1g}}{A}{B}{B}{A' }{A''}{A''}
\rowseven{B_{2g}}{B}{A}{B}{A''}{A' }{A''}
\rowseven{B_{3g}}{B}{B}{A}{A''}{A''}{A' }
\rowseven{A_u   }{A}{A}{A}{A''}{A''}{A''}
\rowseven{B_{1u}}{A}{B}{B}{A''}{A' }{A' }
\rowseven{B_{2u}}{B}{A}{B}{A' }{A''}{A' }
\rowseven{B_{3u}}{B}{B}{A}{A' }{A' }{A''} \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc} \hline
D_\mathrm{3h} & C_\mathrm{3h} & C_\mathrm{3v} & C_\mathrm{2v}               & C_\mathrm{s} & C_\mathrm{s} \\
              &               &               & \mirror{h}\to\mirror{v}(yz) & \mirror{h}   & \mirror{v}   \\ \hline
\rowsix{A_1' }{A' }{A_1}{A_1    }{A'  }{A'    }
\rowsix{A_2' }{A' }{A_2}{B_2    }{A'  }{A''   }
\rowsix{E'   }{E' }{E  }{A_1+B_2}{2A' }{A'+A''}
\rowsix{A_1''}{A''}{A_2}{A_2    }{A'' }{A''   }
\rowsix{A_2''}{A''}{A_1}{B_1    }{A'' }{A'    }
\rowsix{E''  }{E''}{E  }{A_2+B_1}{2A''}{A'+A''} \hline
\end{array} \\
\text{also: }D_3, C_3, C_2$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc} \hline
D_\mathrm{4h} & D_\mathrm{2d} & D_\mathrm{2d}  & D_\mathrm{2h} & D_\mathrm{2h} & D_\mathrm{2} & D_\mathrm{2} \\
              & C_2' \to C_2' & C_2'' \to C_2' & C_2'          & C_2''         & C_2'         & C_2''        \\ \hline
\rowseven{A_{1g}}{A_1}{A_1}{A_g          }{A_g          }{A      }{A      }
\rowseven{A_{2g}}{A_2}{A_2}{B_{1g}       }{B_{1g}       }{B_1    }{B_1    }
\rowseven{B_{1g}}{B_1}{B_2}{A_g          }{B_{1g}       }{A      }{B_1    }
\rowseven{B_{2g}}{B_2}{B_1}{B_{1g}       }{A_g          }{B_1    }{A      }
\rowseven{E_g   }{E  }{E  }{B_{2g}+B_{3g}}{B_{2g}+B_{3g}}{B_2+B_3}{B_2+B_3}
\rowseven{A_{1u}}{B_1}{B_1}{A_u          }{A_u          }{A      }{A      }
\rowseven{A_{2u}}{B_2}{B_2}{B_{1u}       }{B_{1u}       }{B_1    }{B_1    }
\rowseven{B_{1u}}{A_1}{A_2}{A_u          }{B_{1u}       }{A      }{B_1    }
\rowseven{B_{2u}}{A_2}{A_1}{B_{1u}       }{A_u          }{B_1    }{A      }
\rowseven{E_u   }{E  }{E  }{B_{2u}+B_{3u}}{B_{2u}+B_{3u}}{B_2+B_3}{B_2+B_3} \hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc} \hline
D_\mathrm{4h}  & C_\mathrm{4h} & C_\mathrm{4v} & C_\mathrm{2v}{}^\dagger & C_\mathrm{2v}{}^\dagger  \\
\text{(cont.)} &       &       & C_2,\mirror{v}          & C_2,\mirror{d}           \\ \hline
\rowfive{A_{1g}}{A_g}{A_1}{A_1    }{A_1    }
\rowfive{A_{2g}}{A_g}{A_2}{A_2    }{A_2    }
\rowfive{B_{1g}}{B_g}{B_1}{A_1    }{A_2    }
\rowfive{B_{2g}}{B_g}{B_2}{A_2    }{A_1    }
\rowfive{E_g   }{E_g}{E  }{B_1+B_2}{B_1+B_2}
\rowfive{A_{1u}}{A_u}{A_2}{A_2    }{A_2    }
\rowfive{A_{2u}}{A_u}{A_1}{A_1    }{A_1    }
\rowfive{B_{1u}}{B_u}{B_2}{A_2    }{A_1    }
\rowfive{B_{2u}}{B_u}{B_1}{A_1    }{A_2    }
\rowfive{E_u   }{E_u}{E  }{B_1+B_2}{B_1+B_2} \hline
\end{array} \\
\text{also: }D_4, C_4, S_4, C_\mathrm{2v}(C_2'), C_\mathrm{2v}(C_2''), C_\mathrm{2h}(C_2), C_\mathrm{2h}(C_2'), C_\mathrm{2h}(C_2''), C_2(C_2), C_2(C_2'), C_2(C_2''), C_\mathrm{s}(\mirror{h}), C_\mathrm{s}(\mirror{v}), C_\mathrm{s}(\mirror{d}), C_\mathrm{i}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc} \hline
D_\mathrm{6h} & D_\mathrm{3d} & D_\mathrm{3d} & D_\mathrm{2h}            & C_\mathrm{6v} & C_\mathrm{3v} & C_\mathrm{3v} \\
              & C_2''         & C_2'          & \mirror{h}\to\sigma(xy)  &               & \mirror{v}    & \mirror{d}    \\
     &      &      & \mirror{v}\to\sigma(yz)  &     &      &      \\ \hline
\rowseven{A_{1g}}{A_{1g}}{A_{1g}}{A_g          }{A_1}{A_1}{A_1}
\rowseven{A_{2g}}{A_{2g}}{A_{2g}}{B_{1g}       }{A_2}{A_2}{A_2}
\rowseven{B_{1g}}{A_{2g}}{A_{1g}}{B_{2g}       }{B_2}{A_2}{A_1}
\rowseven{B_{2g}}{A_{1g}}{A_{2g}}{B_{3g}       }{B_1}{A_1}{A_2}
\rowseven{E_{1g}}{E_{g} }{E_{g} }{B_{2g}+B_{3g}}{E_1}{E  }{E  }
\rowseven{E_{2g}}{E_{g} }{E_{g} }{A_g+B_{1g}   }{E_2}{E  }{E  }
\rowseven{A_{1u}}{A_{1u}}{A_{1u}}{A_u          }{A_2}{A_2}{A_2}
\rowseven{A_{2u}}{A_{2u}}{A_{2u}}{B_{1u}       }{A_1}{A_1}{A_1}
\rowseven{B_{1u}}{A_{2u}}{A_{1u}}{B_{2u}       }{B_1}{A_1}{A_2}
\rowseven{B_{2u}}{A_{1u}}{A_{2u}}{B_{3u}       }{B_2}{A_2}{A_1}
\rowseven{E_{1u}}{E_{u} }{E_{u} }{B_{2u}+B_{3u}}{E_1}{E  }{E  }
\rowseven{E_{2u}}{E_{u} }{E_{u} }{A_u+B_{1u}   }{E_2}{E  }{E  } \hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc} \hline
D_\mathrm{6h}  & C_\mathrm{2v}           & C_\mathrm{2v}           & C_\mathrm{2h} & C_\mathrm{2h} & C_\mathrm{2h} \\
\text{(cont.)} & C_2'                    & C_2''                   & C_2           & C_2'          & C_2''         \\ 
               & \mirror{h}\to\sigma(xz) & \mirror{h}\to\sigma(xz) &               &               &               \\ \hline
\rowsix{A_{1g}}{A_1    }{A_1    }{A_g }{A_g    }{A_g    }
\rowsix{A_{2g}}{B_1    }{B_1    }{A_g }{B_g    }{B_g    }
\rowsix{B_{1g}}{A_2    }{B_2    }{B_g }{A_g    }{B_g    }
\rowsix{B_{2g}}{B_2    }{A_2    }{B_g }{B_g    }{A_g    }
\rowsix{E_{1g}}{A_2+B_2}{A_2+B_2}{2B_g}{A_g+B_g}{A_g+B_g}
\rowsix{E_{2g}}{A_1+B_1}{A_1+B_1}{2A_g}{A_g+B_g}{A_g+B_g}
\rowsix{A_{1u}}{A_2    }{A_2    }{A_u }{A_u    }{A_u    }
\rowsix{A_{2u}}{B_2    }{B_2    }{A_u }{B_u    }{B_u    }
\rowsix{B_{1u}}{A_1    }{B_1    }{B_u }{A_u    }{B_u    }
\rowsix{B_{2u}}{B_1    }{A_1    }{B_u }{B_u    }{A_u    }
\rowsix{E_{1u}}{A_1+B_1}{A_1+B_1}{2B_u}{A_u+B_u}{A_u+B_u}
\rowsix{E_{2u}}{A_2+B_2}{A_2+B_2}{2A_u}{A_u+B_u}{A_u+B_u} \hline
\end{array} \\
\text{also: }D_6, D_\mathrm{3h}(C_2'), D_\mathrm{3h}(C_2''), C_\mathrm{6h}, C_6, C_\mathrm{3h}, D_3(C_2'), D_3(C_2''), S_6, D_2, C_3, C_2(C_2), C_2(C_2'), C_2(C_2''), C_\mathrm{s}(\mirror{h}), C_\mathrm{s}(\mirror{d}), C_\mathrm{s}(\mirror{v}), C_\mathrm{i} $$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc} \hline
T_\mathrm{d} & T & D_\mathrm{2d} & C_\mathrm{3v} & C_\mathrm{2v}{}^\dagger \\ \hline
\rowfive{A_1}{A}{A_1    }{A_1  }{A_1        }
\rowfive{A_2}{A}{B_1    }{A_2  }{A_2        }
\rowfive{E  }{E}{A_1+B_1}{E    }{A_1+A_2    }
\rowfive{T_1}{T}{A_2+E  }{A_2+E}{A_2+B_1+B_2}
\rowfive{T_2}{T}{B_2+E  }{A_1+E}{A_1+B_1+B_2} \hline
\end{array} \\
\text{also: }S_4, D_2, C_3, C_2, C_\mathrm{s}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc} \hline
O_\mathrm{h} & O & T_\mathrm{d} & T_\mathrm{h} & D_\mathrm{4h} & D_\mathrm{2d} & C_\mathrm{4v} & C_\mathrm{2v}{}^\dagger   \\
             &   &              &              &               &               &               & C_2,\mirror{h},\mirror{d} \\ \hline
\roweight{A_{1g}}{A_1}{A_1}{A_g}{A_{1g}       }{A_1    }{A_1    }{A_1        }
\roweight{A_{2g}}{A_2}{A_2}{A_g}{B_{1g}       }{B_1    }{B_1    }{A_2        }
\roweight{E_g   }{E  }{E  }{E_g}{A_{1g}+B_{1g}}{A_1+B_1}{A_1+B_1}{A_1+A_2    }
\roweight{T_{1g}}{T_1}{T_1}{T_g}{A_{2g}+E_g   }{A_2+E  }{A_2+E  }{A_2+B_1+B_2}
\roweight{T_{2g}}{T_2}{T_2}{T_g}{B_{2g}+E_g   }{B_2+E  }{B_2+E  }{A_1+B_1+B_2}
\roweight{A_{1u}}{A_1}{A_2}{A_u}{A_{1u}       }{B_1    }{A_2    }{A_2        }
\roweight{A_{2u}}{A_2}{A_1}{A_u}{B_{1u}       }{A_1    }{B_2    }{A_1        }
\roweight{E_u   }{E  }{E  }{E_u}{A_{1u}+B_{1u}}{A_1+B_1}{A_2+B_2}{A_1+A_2    }
\roweight{T_{1u}}{T_1}{T_2}{T_u}{A_{2u}+E_u   }{B_2+E  }{A_1+E  }{A_1+B_1+B_2}
\roweight{T_{2u}}{T_2}{T_1}{T_u}{B_{2u}+E_u   }{A_2+E  }{B_1+E  }{A_2+B_1+B_2} \hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc} \hline
O_\mathrm{h}   & D_\mathrm{3d} & D_3 & C_\mathrm{2h} \\
\text{(cont.)} &               &     & C_2           \\ \hline
\rowfour{A_{1g}}{A_{1g}    }{A_1  }{A_g     }
\rowfour{A_{2g}}{A_{2g}    }{A_2  }{B_g     }
\rowfour{E_g   }{E_g       }{E    }{A_g+B_g }
\rowfour{T_{1g}}{A_{2g}+E_g}{A_2+E}{A_g+2B_g}
\rowfour{T_{2g}}{A_{1g}+E_g}{A_1+E}{2A_g+B_g}
\rowfour{A_{1u}}{A_{1u}    }{A_1  }{A_u     }
\rowfour{A_{2u}}{A_{2u}    }{A_2  }{B_u     }
\rowfour{E_u   }{E_u       }{E    }{A_u+B_u }
\rowfour{T_{1u}}{A_{2u}+E_u}{A_2+E}{A_u+2B_u}
\rowfour{T_{2u}}{A_{1u}+E_u}{A_1+E}{2A_u+B_u} \hline
\end{array} \\
\text{Note that }C_2' \equiv C_4^2\text{ and }C_2 \not\equiv C_4^2\text{.} \\
\text{also: }T, D_4, C_\mathrm{4h}, D_\mathrm{2h}(3C_2), D_\mathrm{2h}(3C_2'), C_\mathrm{3v}, S_6, C_4, S_4, C_\mathrm{2v}(C_2',2\mirror{h}), C_\mathrm{2v}(C_2',\mirror{h},\mirror{d}), D_2(3C_2), D_2(3C_2'), C_\mathrm{2h}(C_2'), C_3, C_2(C_2), C_2(C_2'), S_2, C_\mathrm{s}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc} \hline
\mathrm{R_3} & O & D_4 & D_3 \\ \hline
\rowfour{S}{A_1          }{A_1                }{A_1        }
\rowfour{P}{T_1          }{A_2+E              }{A_2+E      }
\rowfour{D}{E+T_2        }{A_1+B_1+B_2+E      }{A_1+2E     }
\rowfour{F}{A_2+T_1+T_2  }{A_2+B_1+B_2+2E     }{A_1+2A_1+2E}
\rowfour{G}{A_1+E+T_1+T_2}{2A_1+A_2+B_1+B_2+2E}{2A_1+A_2+3E}
\rowfour{H}{E+2T_1+2T_2  }{A_1+2A_2+B_1+B_2+3E}{A_1+2A_1+4E} \hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Comment: For those of us without Wilson, Decius, and Cross, it would be nice to have the D2h table, just saying...

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon, your wish is my command...

Comment: Maybe you could add also the tables from [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/107831/53653), so they won't be missing.

Comment: @Eenoku Thanks. Ideally we would have more subgroups in the tables. I may look in the book that porphyrin suggested (in your question), but it’s a low priority thing at the moment.

Comment: @orthocresol Of course, it's just a suggestion ;)

Answer (score 1):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### $C_{\infty\mathrm{v}}$ and $D_{\infty\mathrm{h}}$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|cc} \hline
C_{\infty\mathrm{v}}  & E & 2C_\infty^\phi & \cdots & \infty\sigma_\mathrm{v} &  & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} \equiv \Sigma^+ & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & z & x^2 + y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} \equiv \Sigma^- & 1 & 1 & \cdots & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{E_1} \equiv \Pi      & 2 & 2 \cos\phi & \cdots & 0 & (x,y), (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_2} \equiv \Delta   & 2 & 2 \cos 2\phi & \cdots & 0 & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\
\mathrm{E_3} \equiv \Phi     & 2 & 2 \cos 3\phi & \cdots & 0 & & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &  & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\small \begin{array}{c|cccccccc|cc} \hline
D_{\infty\mathrm{h}} & E & 2C_\infty^\phi & \cdots & \infty\sigma_\mathrm{v} & i & 2S_\infty^\phi & \cdots & \infty C_2 & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_{1g}} \equiv \Sigma^+_{\mathrm{g}} & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 &  & x^2 + y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_{2g}} \equiv \Sigma^-_{\mathrm{g}} & 1 & 1 & \cdots & -1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{E_{1g}} \equiv \Pi_{\mathrm{g}} & 2 & 2\cos\phi & \cdots & 0 & 2 & -2\cos\phi & \cdots & 0 & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_{2g}} \equiv \Delta_{\mathrm{g}} & 2 & 2\cos 2\phi & \cdots & 0 & 2 & 2\cos 2\phi & \cdots & 0 & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \\
\mathrm{A_{1u}} \equiv \Sigma^+_{\mathrm{u}} & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1 & z & \\
\mathrm{A_{2u}} \equiv \Sigma^-_{\mathrm{u}} & 1 & 1 & \cdots & -1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & 1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_{1u}} \equiv \Pi_{\mathrm{u}} & 2 & 2\cos\phi & \cdots & 0 & -2 & 2\cos\phi & \cdots & 0 & (x,y) & \\
\mathrm{E_{2u}} \equiv \Delta_{\mathrm{u}} & 2 & 2\cos 2\phi & \cdots & 0 & -2 & -2\cos 2\phi & \cdots & 0 & & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Answer (score 1):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### $C_n$ $(2 \leq n \leq 8)$

$$\begin{array}{c|cc|cc}\hline
C_2 & E & C_2 & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & z, R_z & x^2, y^2, z^2, xy \\
\mathrm{B} & 1 & -1 & x, y, R_x, R_y & xz, yz \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc|cc}
\hline
C_3 & E & C_3 & C_3^2 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/3) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & z, R_z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{E} & \left\{ \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \left. \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned}\right\} & (x, y), (R_x, R_y) & (x^2-y^2,xy), (xz, yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|cc}
\hline
C_4 & E & C_4 & C_2 & C_4^3 & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & z, R_z & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{B} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & & x^2-y^2,xy \\
\mathrm{E} & \left\{ \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i} \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \left. \begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i} \end{aligned}\right\} & (x, y), (R_x, R_y) & (xz, yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc|cc}
\hline
C_5 & E & C_5 & C_5^2 & C_5^3 & C_5^4 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/5) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & z, R_z & x^2 + y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{E_1} & \left\{ \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^2 \\ \varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*2} \\ \varepsilon^2\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} \right\} & (x,y), (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_2} & \left\{ \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^2 \\ \varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*2} \\ \varepsilon^2\end{aligned} \right\} & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc|cc}\hline
C_6 & E & C_6 & C_3 & C_2 & C_3^2 & C_6^5 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/6) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & z,R_z & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{B} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_1} & \left\{ \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned}\right\} & (x,y),(R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_2} & \left\{ \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned}\right\} & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccc|cc}\hline
C_7 & E & C_7 & C_7^2 & C_7^3 & C_7^4 & C_7^5 & C_7^6 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/7) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & z, R_z & x^2 + y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{E_1} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^2 \\ \varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^3 \\ \varepsilon^{*3}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*3} \\ \varepsilon^3\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*2} \\ \varepsilon^2\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned}\right\} & (x,y),(R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_2} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^2 \\ \varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*3} \\ \varepsilon^3\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon\\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^3 \\ \varepsilon^{*3}\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*2} \\ \varepsilon^2 \end{aligned}\right\} & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\
\mathrm{E_3} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^3 \\ \varepsilon^{*3}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^2 \\ \varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*2} \\ \varepsilon^2\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*3} \\ \varepsilon^3 \end{aligned}\right\} & & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\small \begin{array}{c|cccccccc|cc} \hline
C_8 & E & C_8 & C_4 & C_8^3 & C_2 & C_8^5 & C_4^3 & C_8^7 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/8) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & z,R_z & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{B} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_1} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned}\right\} & (x,y),(R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_2} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i} \end{aligned}\right\} & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\
\mathrm{E_3} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon \end{aligned}\right\} & & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Answer (score 1):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### $D_{n\mathrm{h}} (2 \leq n \leq 6)$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccc|cc} \hline
D_\mathrm{2h} & E & C_2(z) & C_2(y) & C_2(x) & i & \sigma(xy) & \sigma(xz) & \sigma(yz) & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_g} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2,y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{B_{1g}} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & R_z & xy \\
\mathrm{B_{2g}} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & R_y & xz \\
\mathrm{B_{3g}} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & R_x & yz \\
\mathrm{A_u} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{B_{1u}} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & z & \\
\mathrm{B_{2u}} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & y & \\
\mathrm{B_{3u}} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & x & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc|cc} \hline
D_\mathrm{3h} & E & 2C_3 & 3C_2 & \sigma_\mathrm{h} & 2S_3 & 3\sigma_\mathrm{v} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1'} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2'} & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{E'} & 2 & -1 & 0 & 2 & -1 & 0 & (x,y) & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\
\mathrm{A_1''} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{A_2''} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & z & \\
\mathrm{E''} & 2 & -1 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 0 & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc|cc} \hline
D_\mathrm{4h} & E & 2C_4 & C_2 & 2C_2' & 2C_2'' & i & 2S_4 & \sigma_\mathrm{h} & 2\sigma_\mathrm{v} & 2\sigma_\mathrm{d} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_{1g}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_{2g}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{B_{1g}} & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & & x^2-y^2 \\
\mathrm{B_{2g}} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & & xy \\
\mathrm{E_g} & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{A_{1u}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{A_{2u}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & z & \\
\mathrm{B_{1u}} & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & & \\
\mathrm{B_{2u}} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_u} & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & (x,y) & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\small \begin{array}{c|cccccccc|cc} \hline
D_\mathrm{5h} & E & 2C_5 & 2C_5^2 & 5C_2 & \sigma_\mathrm{h} & 2S_5 & 2S_5^3 & 5\sigma_\mathrm{v} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1'} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2'} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{E_1'} & 2 & 2\cos 72^\circ & 2\cos 144^\circ & 0 & 2 & 2\cos 72^\circ & 2\cos 144^\circ & 0 & (x,y) & \\
\mathrm{E_2'} & 2 & 2\cos 144^\circ & 2\cos 72^\circ & 0 & 2 & 2\cos 144^\circ & 2\cos 72^\circ & 0 & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\
\mathrm{A_1''} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{A_2''} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & z & \\
\mathrm{E_1''} & 2 & 2\cos 72^\circ & 2\cos 144^\circ & 0 & -2 & -2\cos 72^\circ & -2\cos 144^\circ & 0 & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_2''} & 2 & 2\cos 144^\circ & 2\cos 72^\circ & 0 & -2 & -2\cos 144^\circ & -2\cos 72^\circ & 0 & & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\small \begin{array}{c|cccccccccccc|cc} \hline
D_\mathrm{6h} & E & 2C_6 & 2C_3 & C_2 & 3C_2' & 3C_2'' & i & 2S_3 & 2S_6 & \sigma_\mathrm{h} & 3\sigma_\mathrm{d} & 3\sigma_\mathrm{v} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_{1g}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_{2g}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{B_{1g}} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{B_{2g}} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_{1g}} & 2 & 1 & -1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & -1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_{2g}} & 2 & -1 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -1 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\
\mathrm{A_{1u}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{A_{2u}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & z & \\
\mathrm{B_{1u}} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & & \\
\mathrm{B_{2u}} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_{1u}} & 2 & 1 & -1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & (x,y) & \\
\mathrm{E_{2u}} & 2 & -1 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Answer (score 0):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### The full rotation group, $\mathrm{R_3}$

$$
\chi^{(j)}(\phi) = 
\begin{cases} 
\Large\frac{\sin\left[\left(j+\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi\right]}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\phi\right)} & \normalsize \phi \neq 0 \\
\\
2j+1 & \phi = 0
\end{cases}
$$

In $\mathrm{R_3}$, $j$ is confined to the natural numbers ($0,1,2, \ldots$), usually denoted with the symbol $l$ or $L$, and the irreducible representations $\Gamma^{(j)}$ are denoted with the letters

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\hline
j & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \cdots \\ \hline
  & \mathrm{S} & \mathrm{P} & \mathrm{D} & \mathrm{F} & \mathrm{G} & \mathrm{H} & \cdots \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Answer (score 0):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### $D_n (n \leq 2 \leq 6)$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|cc} \hline
D_2 & E & C_2(z) & C_2(y) & C_2(x) & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2, y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{B_1} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & z, R_z & xy \\
\mathrm{B_2} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & y, R_y & xz \\
\mathrm{B_3} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & x, R_x & yz \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc|cc} \hline
D_3 & E & 2C_3 & 3C_2 & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & -1 & z, R_z & \\
\mathrm{E} & 2 & -1 & 0 & (x,y),(R_x,R_y) & (x^2-y^2,xy), (xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc|cc} \hline
D_4 & E & 2C_4 & C_2 = C_4^2 & 2C_2' & 2C_2'' & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & z, R_z & \\ 
\mathrm{B_1} & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & & x^2-y^2 \\
\mathrm{B_2} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & & xy \\
\mathrm{E} & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & (x,y), (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|cc} \hline
D_5 & E & 2C_5 & 2C_5^2 & 5C_2 & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & z, R_z & \\
\mathrm{E_1} & 2 & 2\cos 72^\circ & 2\cos 144^\circ & 0 & (x,y),(R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_2} & 2 & 2\cos 144^\circ & 2\cos 72^\circ & 0 & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc|cc} \hline
D_6 & E & 2C_6 & 2C_3 & C_2 & 3C_2' & 3C_2'' & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & z, R_z & \\
\mathrm{B_1} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{B_2} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_1} & 2 & 1 & -1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & (x,y),(R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\ 
\mathrm{E_2} & 2 & -1 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Answer (score 0):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### $C_{n\mathrm{h}} (2 \leq n \leq 6)$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{2h} & E & C_2 & i & \sigma_\mathrm{h} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_g} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & R_z & x^2, y^2, z^2, xy \\
\mathrm{B_g} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & R_x, R_y & xz, yz \\
\mathrm{A_u} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & z & \\
\mathrm{B_u} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & x, y & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{3h} & E & C_3 & C_3^2 & \sigma_\mathrm{h} & S_3 & S_3^5 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/3) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A'} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & R_z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{E'} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned}\right\} & (x,y) & (x^2-y^2, xy) \\ 
\mathrm{A''} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & z & \\
\mathrm{E''} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon\end{aligned}\right\} & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccc|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{4h} & E & C_4 & C_2 & C_4^3 & i & S_4^3 & \sigma_\mathrm{h} & S_4 & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_g} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & R_z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{B_g} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & & x^2-y^2, xy \\
\mathrm{E_g} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned}\right\} & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{A_u} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & z & \\
\mathrm{B_u} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_u} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned}\right\} & (x,y) & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\small \begin{array}{c|cccccccccc|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{5h} & E & C_5 & C_5^2 & C_5^3 & C_5^4 & \sigma_\mathrm{h} & S_5 & S_5^7 & S_5^3 & S_5^9 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/5) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A'} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & R_z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{E_1'} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1\\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^2 \\ \varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*2} \\ \varepsilon^2\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1\\ 1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^2 \\ \varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*2} \\ \varepsilon^2\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned}
\right\} & (x,y) & \\
\mathrm{E_2'} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^2 \\ \varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*2} \\ \varepsilon^2\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^2 \\ \varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*2} \\ \varepsilon^2\end{aligned}\right\} & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\
\mathrm{A''} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & z & \\
\mathrm{E_1''} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1\\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^2 \\ \varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*2} \\ \varepsilon^2\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1\\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^2 \\ -\varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^{*2} \\ -\varepsilon^2\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon\end{aligned}
\right\} & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_2''} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^2 \\ \varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^{*2} \\ \varepsilon^2\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^2 \\ -\varepsilon^{*2}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^{*2} \\ -\varepsilon^2\end{aligned}\right\} & & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\small \begin{array}{c|cccccccccccc|cc} \hline
C_\mathrm{6h} & E & C_6 & C_3 & C_2 & C_3^2 & C_6^5 & i & S_3^5 & S_6^5 & \sigma_\mathrm{h} & S_6 & S_3 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/6) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_g} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & R_z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{B_g} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_{1g}} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned} -1 \\ -1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned} -1 \\ -1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned}\right\} & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_{2g}} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned} 1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned} 1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon \end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^* \end{aligned}\right\} & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\
\mathrm{A_u} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & z & \\
\mathrm{B_u} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 &1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & & \\
\mathrm{E_{1u}} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned} -1 \\ -1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned} 1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon \end{aligned}\right\} & (x,y) & \\
\mathrm{E_{2u}} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1 \end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned} 1 \\ 1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned} -1 \\ -1 \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^* \end{aligned}\right\} & & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Comment: Oh, the horrors of an overfull hbox... I haven't figured out how to adjust the column padding in MathJax (or whether it's possible to begin with), so...

Answer (score 0):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### $D_{n\mathrm{d}} (2 \leq n \leq 6)$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc|cc} \hline
D_\mathrm{2d} & E & 2S_4 & C_2 & 2C_2' & 2\sigma_\mathrm{d} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{B_1} & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & & x^2-y^2 \\
\mathrm{B_2} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & z & xy & \\
\mathrm{E} & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & (x,y),(R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc|cc} \hline
D_\mathrm{3d} & E & 2C_3 & 3C_2 & i & 2S_6 & 3\sigma_\mathrm{d} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_{1g}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_{2g}} & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{E_g} & 2 & -1 & 0 & 2 & -1 & 0 & (R_x,R_y) & (x^2-y^2,xy),(xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{A_{1u}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{A_{2u}} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & z & \\
\mathrm{E_u} & 2 & -1 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 0 & (x,y) & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccc|cc} \hline
D_\mathrm{4d} & E & 2S_8 & 2C_4 & 2S_8^3 & C_2 & 4C_2' & 4\sigma_\mathrm{d} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{B_1} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{B_2} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & z & \\
\mathrm{E_1} & 2 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & -\sqrt{2} & -2 & 0 & 0 & (x,y) & \\
\mathrm{E_2} & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\
\mathrm{E_3} & 2 & -\sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{2} & -2 & 0 & 0 & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\small\begin{array}{c|cccccccc|cc} \hline
D_\mathrm{5d} & E & 2C_5 & 2C_5^2 & 5C_2 & i & 2S_{10}^3 & 2S_{10} & 5\sigma_\mathrm{d} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_{1g}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_{2g}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{E_{1g}} & 2 & 2\cos 72^\circ & 2\cos 144^\circ & 0 & 2 & 2\cos 72^\circ & 2\cos 144^\circ & 0 & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{E_{2g}} & 2 & 2\cos 144^\circ & 2\cos 72^\circ & 0 & 2 & 2\cos 144^\circ & 2\cos 72^\circ & 0 & & \begin{aligned}(x^2-y^2,\\ xy)\,\,\,\,\,\end{aligned} \\
\mathrm{A_{1u}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{A_{2u}} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & z & \\
\mathrm{E_{1u}} & 2 & 2\cos 72^\circ & 2\cos 144^\circ & 0 & -2 & -2\cos 72^\circ & -2\cos 144^\circ & 0 & (x,y) & \\
\mathrm{E_{2u}} & 2 & 2\cos 144^\circ & 2\cos 72^\circ & 0 & -2 & -2\cos 144^\circ & -2\cos 72^\circ & 0 & & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc|cc} \hline
D_\mathrm{6d} & E & 2S_{12} & 2C_6 & 2S_4 & 2C_3 & 2S_{12}^5 & C_2 & 6C_2' & 6\sigma_\mathrm{d} & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2,z^2 \\
\mathrm{A_2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & R_z & \\
\mathrm{B_1} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{B_2} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & z & \\
\mathrm{E_1} & 2 & \sqrt{3} & 1 & 0 & -1 & -\sqrt{3} & -2 & 0 & 0 & (x,y) & \\
\mathrm{E_2} & 2 & 1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & & (x^2-y^2,xy) \\
\mathrm{E_3} & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & & \\
\mathrm{E_4} & 2 & -1 & -1 & 2 & -1 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & & \\
\mathrm{E_5} & 2 & -\sqrt{3} & 1 & 0 & -1 & \sqrt{3} & -2 & 0 & 0 & (R_x,R_y) & (xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Answer (score 0):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### $S_n (n = 4,6,8)$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc|cc}\hline
S_4 & E & S_4 & C_2 & S_4^3 & & \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & R_z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{B} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & z & x^2-y^2, xy \\
\mathrm{E} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned}\right\} & (x,y), (R_x, R_y) & (xz, yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc|cc} \hline
S_6 & E & C_3 & C_3^2 & i & S_6^5 & S_6 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/3) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_g} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & R_z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{E_g} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned}\right\} & (R_x,R_y) & (x^2-y^2, xy), (xz,yz) \\
\mathrm{A_u} & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & z & \\
\mathrm{E_u} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon\end{aligned}\right\} & (x,y) & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\small\begin{array}{c|cccccccc|cc} \hline
S_8 & E & S_8 & C_4 & S_8^3 & C_2 & S_8^5 & C_4^3 & S_8^7 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/8) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & R_z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{B} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & z & \\
\mathrm{E_1} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned}\right\} & (x,y) & \\
\mathrm{E_2} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned}\right\} & & (x^2-y^2, xy) \\
\mathrm{E_3} & \left\{\begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned}\right. & \begin{aligned}-\varepsilon^* \\ -\varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-\mathrm{i} \\ \mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^*\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}-1 \\ -1\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon\end{aligned} & \begin{aligned}\mathrm{i} \\ -\mathrm{i}\end{aligned} & \left.\begin{aligned}-\varepsilon \\ -\varepsilon^*\end{aligned}\right\} & (R_x, R_y) & (xz,yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

In the point group $S_8$, $(R_x,R_y)$ actually transforms as $\mathrm{E_3}$, *not* $\mathrm{E_1}$. This runs contrary to many other sources (which are, unfortunately, all incorrect). Please see: [*J. Chem. Educ.* **2007,** *84* (11), 1882](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed084p1882) for further clarification on this matter.

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

Answer (score 0):

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)

### Icosahedral groups: $I, I_\mathrm{h}$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc|cc} \hline
I & E & 12C_5 & 12C_5^2 & 20C_3 & 15C_2 & & \eta^{\pm} = \frac{1}{2}(1\pm\sqrt{5}) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2+z^2 \\
\mathrm{T_1} & 3 & \eta^+ & \eta^- & 0 & -1 & (x,y,z),(R_x,R_y,R_z) & \\
\mathrm{T_2} & 3 & \eta^- & \eta^+ & 0 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{G} & 4 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & & \\
\mathrm{H} & 5 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & & \begin{aligned}(2z^2-x^2-y^2,\,\,\,\,\, \\ x^2-y^2, xy, yz, xz)\end{aligned} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$\,$

$$\small\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc|cc} \hline
I_\mathrm{h} & E & 12C_5 & 12C_5^2 & 20C_3 & 15C_2 & i & 12S_{10} & 12S_{10}^3 & 20S_6 & 15\sigma & & \eta^{\pm} = \frac{1}{2}(1\pm\sqrt{5}) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A_g} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & x^2+y^2+z^2 \\
\mathrm{T_{1g}} & 3 & \eta^+ & \eta^- & 0 & -1 & 3 & \eta^- & \eta^+ & 0 & -1 & \begin{aligned}(R_x,R_y,\\R_z)\,\,\,\,\end{aligned} & \\
\mathrm{T_{2g}} & 3 & \eta^- & \eta^+ & 0 & -1 & 3 & \eta^+ & \eta^- & 0 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{G_g} & 4 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 4 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & & \\
\mathrm{H_g} & 5 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 5 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & & \begin{aligned}(2z^2-x^2-y^2, \\ x^2-y^2,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \\ xy, yz, xz)\,\,\,\,\,\end{aligned} \\
\mathrm{A_u} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & & \\
\mathrm{T_{1u}} & 3 & \eta^+ & \eta^- & 0 & -1 & -3 & -\eta^- & -\eta^+ & 0 & 1 & (x,y,z) & \\
\mathrm{T_{2u}} & 3 & \eta^- & \eta^+ & 0 & -1 & -3 & -\eta^+ & -\eta^- & 0 & 1 & & \\
\mathrm{G_u} & 4 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & -4 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & & \\
\mathrm{H_u} & 5 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -5 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

[(back to top)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#)